# On a ring $R$ where $x^2 = x$, we must have that $2x = 0$ and $R$ is commutative

Tags: ring-theory

I want to show that on a ring $R$ where $x^2 = x$ for all elements $x$, we must have that $2x = 0$ and $R$ is commutative. Does my answer look sound?

Well, if $x = 0$ we have that $x^2 = x$ is trivially true.

If $x \neq 0$ then $x^2 = x$

$\Longleftrightarrow x \cdot x = x$

$\Longleftrightarrow x \cdot x \cdot x^{-1} = x \cdot x^{-1}$

$\Longleftrightarrow x = 1$

I.e. the only non-zero element that we can possibly find in $R$ is $1$.

So $R = \{0, 1\}$ and as $1 + 0 = 1$ the only way we can satisfy the additive inverse ring axiom is if $1 + 1 = 0$.

I.e. $2(1) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow 2x = 0$

$R$ must be commutative because if we take two elements from $R$, e.g. take $a = 0$ and $b = 0$ such that $ab \neq ba$ we will have that $ab$ is either $0$ or $1$.

$ab = 1$ is not possible as $a = b = 0$.

If $ab = 0 \implies ba = 1$ and this is not possible as again $a = b = 0$.

Comment: I don't see it as an assumption, but does $x^{-1}$ exist in $R$, for all $x\in R$?

Comment: [Boolean rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring#Examples) There are many examples of rings satisfying this other than $\{0,1\}$

Comment: @J.Maglione Hmmm, good point. That isn't specified in the question so I take it that invalidates my answer?

Comment: What you have shown is that if $R$ is a *field* where $x^2=x$ for all $x\in R,$ then $R$ is the field with two elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the existence of multiplicative inverses because they don't necessarily exist (consider the inverse of $2$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$), but there's a different approach that only needs the existence of the multiplicative identity $1$; since $x^2=x$ for all $x$, then likewise $(x+1)^2=x+1$ for all $x$.  Now, expand out the LHS and do some *additive* cancellations (since addition *is* a group operation and so has a proper inverse) and you should see the conclusion.  Once you have $x+x=0$ for all $x$ then commutativity can be proven as a separate step.

Comment: +1: This captures the problem nicely. There's really no need to worry about commutativity of multiplication, though.

Comment: @CameronBuie I realized that after posting it - I'll clean up this answer, since that's somewhat a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

The party line on this problem, since I am such a good party member!:  since for all $x \in R$ we have $x^2 =x$, it follows that

$(x + y)^2 = x + y, \tag{1}$

or

$x^2 + xy + yx + y^2 = x + y, \tag{2}$

or

$x + xy + yx + y = x + y, \tag{3}$

or

$xy + yx = 0, \tag{4}$

whence taking $y = x$,

$2x = x + x = x^2 + x^2 = 0, \tag{5}$

and thus we also have

$x = -x \tag{6}$

holding for all $x \in R$.  Now we see that

$xy = -yx = yx \tag{7}$

follows from (4) and (6).  Equations (4)-(7) express the requisite conclusions.***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***